# c++ EXC_BAD_ACCESS in linked list

Tags: c++

I want to create basic Linked list app with c++ but I get this error :
[image]

Here is my node class :

```
class node {
    friend class graph;
    int n;
    node *next;
};
```

and here is my graph class:

```
class graph{
private:
    node *first;
    node *last;
public:
    void input();
    void show();
    graph();
};

graph::graph(){
    first = NULL;
    last = NULL;
}
```

I want to create node from number that user insert

```
void graph::input(){
    node *n1 = new node();
    std::cout << "Please Enter Number \n";
    std::cin >> n1->n;
    n1->next = NULL;
    if (first==NULL){
        first = last = n1;
    }
    else{
        last->next = n1;
        last = n1;
    }
}
```

in the end I want to show number but I get error !

```
void graph::show(){
    node *current = first;
    do {
        std::cout << "///////////////\n" << current->n;
        current = current->next;
    }while (current->next == NULL);
}


int main() {
    graph g = *new graph();
    g.input();
    g.show();
}
```

Please let me know How can I fix this error and why I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the code you have written. The correct way is:

```
void graph::show()
{
    node *current = first;
    do 
    {
        std::cout << "///////////////\n" << current->n;
        current = current->next;
    }while (current != NULL);
}
```

if the while condition is like

```
current->next != NULL
```

then it will dump provided only one element present in the list or in some other scenario as well

Comment: Thank's for your answer